# mono ignores dllmaps in the app.config file

Tags: linux, mono

It seem Mono ignores dllmaps in the local configuration file.

I want to port my .NET application on Linux (ubuntu) which calls native libraries so I have dllmaps to make my code work. The mono docs says you have to make a something.exe.config for something.exe and put application specific configs in it. it parses the file (because it complains if I make some spelling mistakes in it) and the filename is correct but it seems it ignores the dllmaps.

The config file is simple:

```
<configuration>
<dllmap dll="i:openal32.dll" target="libopenal.so" />
</configuration>
```

Mono does not find the openal32.dll and throws DllNotFoundException. But if I copy that dllmap entry in the main /etc/mono/config file then everything is fine. 
If do a $MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono... trick to see what it does and I see there is no attempt to load libopenal.so at all. But many tries to load libopenal32.dll, ./libopenal32.dll libopenal32.so, openal32.so, etc. files.

Probably I ran into a Mono bug again?

I want to pack this config file in the archive and I don't want to ask my users to mess with the /etc/mono/config file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are all of your DllImport attributes in the code using "openal32.dll" or are some using "openal32" instead?
In any case the config file refers to the assembly that contains the P/Invoke methods: the most likely issue is that you created the config for the main assembly while the P/Invoke methods are in a separate library assembly.
Just rename the file to OpenAlUsingAssembly.dll.config.

Comment: That was the problem... I wrote the config file to the wrong assembly. One of my references use the dll not the main application.

Comment: +1 you have a bright future writing mono deobfuscation docs. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was just having the same issue whilst trying to run my OpenAL (actually OpenTK) test program under Ubuntu 12.04.  In the end all I needed to do was:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal1
```

In order to get the OpenAL run-time libraries and then create a file called OpenTK.dll.config containing:

```
<configuration>
  <dllmap dll="i:openal32.dll" target="libopenal.so.1" />
</configuration>
```

Which mapped the imports in OpenTK.dll from the windows openal32.dll file to the correct version of the shared library under linux, which is my case is libopenal.so.1 (which actually appears to be just a link to libopenal.so.1.13.0).